# How to Concatenate 2 Columns using SQL in DBeaver connected to Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, dbeaver

Here's an example table:

```
 account_no     season      animal 
      A         spring      sheep
      A         spring      cow
      A         winter      pig
      B         winter      lamb
```

I'm using DBeaver connected to Redshift and I'd like to GROUP BY **account_no** and **season** and concatenate the animals into a single column as shown below:

```
account_no      season     animalList 
     A          spring     sheep, cow
     A          winter     pig   
     B          winter     lamb
```

I've tried the **STRING_AGG** function such as

```
SELECT STRING_AGG(animal,',') AS animalList
FROM Animals
GROUP BY account_no, season
```

However, I'm getting the error below:

```
Error occurred during SQL query execution

Reason: SQL Error [500310] [42883]: [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: function string_agg(character varying, "unknown") does not exist;
```

I've tried adding varchar as suggested by other threads but I'm still getting the same error

```
 SELECT STRING_AGG(animal: : varchar,',') AS animalList
    FROM Animals
    GROUP BY account_no, season
```

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redshift calls the function [`listagg()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_LISTAGG.html):

```
SELECT LISTAGG(animal, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY animal) AS animalList
FROM Animals
GROUP BY account_no, season;
```

This is not unreasonable, because this is the standard name for the function.

Comment: Hi Gordon Linoff, it works! Thank you so much!